# ReactJS Router DOM. Dynamic routes with regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm currently playing around a bit with React Router Dom and i'm questioning if it would be possible to have some dynamic routes.

I know i can have some dynamic routing with the following:

```
<Route path="/component/:param" component={Component} />
```

What i would like to have, is the following:

E.g. I have a filter page. On this page, i have the following filters:

Area

- Florida
- Miami
- New York

Interests

- Webdevelopment
- Social Media
- Marketing

Level

- Beginner
- Intermediate
- Advanced

etc.

My URL should be, when i select Florida as the area, Webdevelopment and Social media as the interests and Beginner as the level, the following

```
/component/filter/areas/florida/interests/webdevelopment;social-media/levels/beginner
```

Above is simple with:

```
<Route path="/component/filter/areas/:areas/interests/:interests/levels/:levels" component={Component} />
```

But, it can also be possible that it is like this:

```
/component/filter/interests/webdevelopment;social-media
```

or

```
/component/filter/areas/new-york
```

or

```
/component/filter/interests/webdevelopment;social-media/areas/new-york
```

Is it possible to have 1 (or 2) Routes with the /component path for all the items and a path for the filters without having to define all the different paths for it? Because when i have, for example, 50 filters, i really don't want to have 1000+ lines for only my filters.

Thank you in advance for you answers!

Comment: this URL pattern is weird. Clearly  `area`, `interests` and `levels` should be in query string. eg: `"/component/filter?area=${encodeURLComponent(areas)}&interests=${encodeURLComponent(interests)}&levels=${encodeURLComponent(levels)}"`

Comment: Can you tell me why it's weird? In my opinion, it's super search engine friendly, and I could create a per filter description above the results. 

 - Find Webdevelopment meetings in New York
 - Find Social media meetings in Florida etc.

Comment: Because all the filter condition you have are in same level (Don't have parent-children relationship). If you extract the value from query string, the order and missing value don't matter. But in your url, you need provide separate route when either `areas` or `interests` is missing.

Comment: Just use localstorage

Answer (score 0):

If you have a few filters which are optional then you could define the Routes like

```
<Route path="/component/filter(/areas/:areas)?(/interests/:interests)?(/levels/:levels)?" component={Component} />
```

However for a large number of filters it really doesn't make sense to have the filters as URL params, rather you should make use of Query params like

and you URL could be like

```
`?areas=new-york&interests=webdevelopment,socialmedia&levels=1`
```

which you can then parse in the component.

> P.S. the above url should be urlencoded

Check this answer on [how you would intergrate and detect change inquery params with react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993247/detect-change-in-query-param-react-router-dom-v4-x-and-re-render-component/48993736#48993736)