# React Router not keeping query

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm sending a query with my link like this:

```
 <Link to={{ 
     pathname: `/forum/${this.state.mainCategoryName}/${category.name}`, 
     query: { subcatid: category.id} }
   }
 >
  {category.name}
 </Link>
```

This is working just fine, and I can render the value like so:

```
 this.props.location.query.subcatid
```

However, as soon as I refresh the page or in some way enter the page in another way except using the link, the query is not being included.

How can I achieve this?

My router looks like this:

```
<Route 
  exact={true} 
  path="/forum/:forumcatid/:forumsubcatid" 
  render={
    (routeProps) => ( 
      <ForumThreads {...routeProps} {...this.props} /> 
    )
  } 
/>
```

Comment: The reason being that query was supplied by the component that caused navigation, however during refresh, that component is no longer causing redirection. However if you add the query params to the url, you can get it after you refresh

Comment: Check this question on how to customize withRouter from react-router v4 to provide query params https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993247/detect-change-in-query-param-react-router-dom-v4-x-and-re-render-component/48993736#48993736

Comment: Thanks, I really don't want to include the id in my URL, that's why I'm trying to send it as props instead. As I mentioned, this is working fine when entering the page via the link, but not other way around. Maybe there isn't a solution for this.

Comment: The only solution that is possible is to store the received query params in localStorage on unmount

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think i'll just add the id as a parameter to the url, plain oldschool :) I just thought there would be a smarter way to keep a clean URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to check with `ComponentDidMount` inside `ForumThreads`. Becouse after full page refresh you didnt `pass` query, it's just there.

```
ComponentDidMount(){
 // here check
 // this.props.location.search 
 // to see if it allready contains some query strings inside url 
 // and then do your magic :)
}
```