# ReactJS - How to find the value of paymentId and render its value in return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

PaymentId should have a value and it should be included in link tag for generating the proper link

```
export default class MkPayment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const query = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
    this.state = {
      paymentId: query.id,
      payeeName: "",
    },
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Link className="border-button ml10" to={{ search: "?id=" + this.state.paymentId + "&retry=true" }}>Retry Payment</Link>
      <p>{this.state.payeeName}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you face

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to find the integer value of paymentId and update in the Link tag

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993247/detect-change-in-query-param-react-router-dom-v4-x-and-re-render-component/48993736#48993736

Comment: Fine, please consider this stepping process: I need to get the paymentId from the previous page and need to store the value in the link tag of the next page. ie., How to find the value of paymentId and set the value in next page