# Get the route path with special character and dynamic variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The path provided in the react router component is not working as expected.

**e.g: path: "/route?name=/:name/&course=/:course/"**

Dynamic variable in the URL: /:name/ and /:course/

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `course` are query params and should not be specified in `Route`.

You can simply have your component Route like

```
path= "/route"
```

and detect query params changes as mentioned in the following post

[Detect change in query param react-router-dom v4.x and re-render component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993247/detect-change-in-query-param-react-router-dom-v4-x-and-re-render-component/48993736#48993736)

or you could design your route to make name and course and path params and have your Route like

```
path: "/route/:name/:course/"
```